# How to apply any sort of Map Transformation on Spark Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using Spark Structure Streaming, the code is in following:

```
 def convert_timestamp_to_datetime(timestamp):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)


 def extract():
       spark = SparkSession \
         .builder \
         .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount") \
         .getOrCreate()

    json_schema = \
         StructType() \
        .add(StructField("TIMESTAMP", FloatType(), True)) \
        .add(StructField("index", IntegerType(), True)) \
        .add(StructField("CUSTOMER_ID", StringType(), True)) \
        .add(StructField("CODE_ID", StringType(), True)) \
        .add(StructField("PROCESS", StringType(), True))

     my_df = spark \
         .readStream \
         .format("kafka") \
         .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
         .option("subscribe", "simple_json_12_10trx") \
         .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
         .load()
     my_df = my_df.select(from_json(col('value').cast('string'), json_schema).alias("json"))
convert_timestamp_datetime_udf = udf(lambda x: convert_timestamp_to_datetime(x), TimestampType())
      return my_df.select('json.*', convert_timestamp_datetime_udf('json.TIMESTAMP').alias('DATETIME'))
  
 def transform_load(my_df, epoch_id):
       update_obj = my_df.groupBy('CUSTOMER_ID').agg(F.count('CUSTOMER_ID').alias('count_t'),F.collect_set('CODE_ID').alias('unique_CODE'))
update_obj.show()
update(update_obj)


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     start = time.time()
     df = extract()
     query = df.writeStream \
        .outputMode('append')\
        .foreachBatch(transform_load)\
        .start() \
        .awaitTermination()
```

I want to access each row of Spark Dataframe distributed. So, I must use Map transformation. I just add this simple code to test Spark Map. But, I do not receive any output in console. In fact, `func` is not run.

```
 def func(df):
      df.take(3)

 def update(df):
      df.rdd.map(func,preservesPartitioning=False)
```

Would you please guide me what is wrong here?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I forgot to use `action` after map. Also, I cannot use `df.take(3)` since there is not any dataframe in `func`, it is `rdd` which does not have `take` attribute. I change the code like this :

```
 def func(x):
    print(x.CUSTOMER_ID)

 def update(df):
    df.rdd.map(func,preservesPartitioning=False).count()
```

`count()` is an action that I use to see map result.